# There is no reaction when I click a button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def player_turn():
    if buttons['text'] == ' ':
        buttons['text'] = 'O'

def cpu_turn():
    if buttons['text'] == ' ':
        x = random.randint(1,9)
        btn_list[x]['text'] = 'X'
        
def game():
    while turns < 10 and not win:
        if turns % 2 == 1:
            player_turn()
        else:
            cpu_turn()


            
def click(buttons):
    global clicked
    global player_score
    global cpu_score
    global win
    if (btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn3['text'] == 'O' or
        btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' or
        btn7['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
        btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
        btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
        btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
        btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' or
        btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O'):
            player_score += 1
            win = True
    elif (btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn3['text'] == 'X' or
        btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' or
        btn7['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
        btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
        btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
        btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
        btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' or
        btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X'):
            cpu_score += 1
            win = True



window = Tk()
window.title('Tic Tac Toe')


buttons = StringVar()

btn1 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn1))
btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)

btn2 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn2))
btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)

btn3 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn3))
btn3.grid(row=1,column=2)

btn4 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn4))
btn4.grid(row=2,column=0)

btn5 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn5))
btn5.grid(row=2,column=1)

btn6 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn6))
btn6.grid(row=2,column=2)

btn7 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn7))
btn7.grid(row=3,column=0)

btn8 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn8))
btn8.grid(row=3,column=1)

btn9 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn9))
btn9.grid(row=3,column=2)

btn_list = [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9]

player_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
turn = 1
win = False
```

When I click the button there is no error but no any effects. Here I would like to set the while loop within changing turns between player and cpu but I do not know what is the best way to produce this kind of effect so could anyone teach me? Also how can I set if the button already has text then can't be clicked afterwards? I would like to ask what is the use of lambda function because I do not know when to use

Comment: If you add `print(buttons)` inside `click()` function, you will find that the function works as expect.  And you did not update the button text upon it is clicked.

Comment: How can I describe the if conditions?

Comment: I do not know how to make cpu random button choice

Answer (score 1):

The code posted above will not run since the tkinter frame is only visible when the script contains the mainloop() function which keeps on running until the window is closed.

So add the following line in the end:

> `window.mainloop()`

Also, since you are calling the click() function along with the button passed, that will be the only function to get executed.
It does not contain a call to any of the three functions namely:

```
game()
cpu_turn()
player_turn()
```